# SQL instruction that shows if there is a value in a another table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have two files, header and detail. In the detail file, there is a key field to find or join header. I need to count the number of header rows that have a detail record. I want to know the number of records with `field1 = 'A'` only, and the number of header rows that have a record with `field1 = 'A'` or `= 'B'`.

It doesn't work with a Join or a `CASE` and `subselect` query.

Here is a simplified example:

- Table AA (header) and table BB (detail). Table AA has field `HeadId`.
- Table BB has three fields: `HeadId`, `DetId` and `Data`. HeadId is used to join with header table. Value of field Data can be equal A or B. An AA row can have more rows on BB.

I need to know how many rows in AA have BB only rows with value of Data = A and how many have both A and B. I need to do this with only a SQL query.

Please can you help me?

Comment: Looks like you need to clarify your question.  SQL is a standardized language for manipulating data that is present in *tables* not "files".  If you are working in an environment that uses some kind of SQL dialect that also works on "files", you should mention this specifically.  If you are working in a regular DBMS evironment using regular SQL tables, you should specify the structure (names, columns, data types) of those tables and preferably also an example input plus expected output.

Comment: Hi! Thank you för answer. I use DBMS DB2/400 database, I write file but I mean tables (sorry!). I try to clarify with a semplified example. I have table AA (header) and table BB (detajl). Table AA have field HeadId. Table BB have three fields HeadId, DetId and Data. HeadId is used to join with header table. Value of field Data can be equal A or B. An AA row can have more rows on BB. I need to know how many rows in AA have i BB only rows with value of Data = A and how many have both A and B. I need to do this with only a SQL instruction.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the output?  Do you just want a single row per entry in AA with two additional columns containing counts of just A and A + B?  Do you need this in a single query or can two different queries work?  Why doesn't a join do the job?  What is wrong with the output?

Answer (score 0):

I used union for this and only the 'BB' table for counting

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, 'Only A' as type
FROM BB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT headId FROM BB WHERE Data != 'A' AND headId = b.headId)
GROUP BY headId, data
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 'A and B'
FROM BB b1
JOIN BB b2 ON b1.headId = b2.headId AND b1.id != b2.id AND b1.data != b2.data
WHERE b1.data IN ('A', 'B') AND b2.data IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY b1.headId
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish the same thing. Basing my code off of Joakim's answer a bit, this one works for me:

```
SELECT headId 
  FROM HEADER;

HEADID
------
     1
     2
     3
     4

select headId,
       detailId,
       someData
  from Detail
;

HEADID     DETAILID  SOMEDATA
------  -----------  --------
     1            1  A       
     2            1  A       
     2            2  B       
     3            1  X       
     4            1  A       

SELECT 'Only A' AS TYPE,
        COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM HEADER H
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DETAIL D
               WHERE D.HEADID = H.HEADID AND SOMEDATA = 'A')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DETAIL D
                   WHERE D.HEADID = H.HEADID AND SOMEDATA <> 'A')
 GROUP BY 'Only A'
UNION
SELECT 'Both A and B' AS TYPE,
        COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM HEADER H
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DETAIL D
               WHERE D.HEADID = H.HEADID AND SOMEDATA = 'A')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DETAIL D
                WHERE D.HEADID = H.HEADID AND SOMEDATA = 'B') 
 GROUP BY 'Both A and B'
;

TYPE                COUNT
------------  -----------
Both A and B            1
Only A                  2
```

Hope that helps!